# How to open All the media files(with in sub folders) in the folder with vlc in linux?

Tags: linux, shell-script, terminal, vlc

I want to open all the media files within a folder and its subfolders. I am able to open within the folder but not files in subfolers.
Is there any linux terminal command to do that.

Thanks,

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you tried globstar or what ever it is called? /base/dir/**/* ?

Comment: [mpv](https://mpv.io/) has this feature. Just type: `mpv /path/to/dir` and mpv creates playlist with all files recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find ... -exec` terminated with `+` like this:

```
find path -type f -exec echo vlc {} +
```

If the output looks good, remove the `echo`.

You might want to add some filters, like `-name`.